# Spring get request data in Dao or service layer

Tags: spring

I m sing spring data MongoDb.  in controller @requestBody User user.

So There is no data in request now. After take it from the request body.

Is there any Way in spring to get the request body data after take it from the request Object in dao layer.. Please help me out. Thx in advance/..

Comment: Could you please post your method here?

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesn't magically store it anywhere, so you have to read it yourself in the controller layer and pass it around as a regular parameter or store somewhere yourself.